# pytest.raises passes when should fails (ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous.)

Tags: dataframe, unit-testing, pytest, valueerror, raise

I am testing my code using pytest.

If I do:

```
response = clients(5)
print(response)
```

I get a dataframe as output (defined in clients function)

```
 client_id    name           country    currency  
 5            John Doe       Spain      EUR
```

clients is defined this way:

```
def clients(id):

    endpoint = f"myendpoint/{id}"
    response = requests.get(endpoint)
    j_response = json.loads(response.text)

    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(j_response))

    return df
```

Then in my tests.py I do

```
import pytest  

test_clients_exceptions():

    with pytest.raises(Exception):
        assert clients(5)
```

I get PASSED, when I should get FAILED since not exceptions should be raised.
If I change "Exception" for "ValueError" it passes, but not if I change to "TypeError", for example. In this case, I get:

```
 ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Why is that?

---

On the other hand, which is the correct syntax if I want to test several raises at once? Is it ok if I do:

```
test_clients_exceptions():

    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        assert clients("this_is_str_and_should_be_int")

    key_dict="Hi"
    value = 4
    with pytest.raises(Exception) as e:
        assert clients(**{key_dict: value})
        assert str(e.value) == f"\'{key_dict}\' is not supported"
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used pytest.raises, another way to do what you want is something like this:

```
try:
    clients(5)
except:
    pytest.fail("My test failed \n", False)
```

Note: False is used if you would not like to display everything that failed in the terminal. But if you want to see everything you can change to True.
source: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest-fail

*I did not understand what the method clients do. This seems not a test.